# Creating and saving a gif in python

Tags: python, animation, plot, gif

I have this code, that makes many plots of a trajectory defined by x, y and z. How do i make a gif out of all of those plots? Right now all I've been able to achieve is saving all n plots on my hard drive and using third party software to make them into a gif.

```
for t in range(len(theta)):
    fig = plt.figure('Parametrinai blynai')
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
    ax.plot(x[1:t], y[1:t], z[1:t], '-r', linewidth=3)

    ax.set_xlabel('X', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontweight='bold', fontsize=14)
    ax.set_xlim([-20, 20])
    ax.set_ylim([-20, 20])
    ax.set_zlim([-10, 10])
    plt.title('Parametrinis blynas', fontweight='bold', fontsize=16)

    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * T[t, 0], emp * T[t, 1], emp * T[t, 2], color='k')
    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * B[t, 0], emp * B[t, 1], emp * B[t, 2], color='b')
    ax.quiver(x[t - 1], y[t - 1], z[t - 1], emp * N[t, 0], emp * N[t, 1], emp * N[t, 2], color='g')
    pavadinimas = str(t)
    plt.savefig(pavadinimas, dpi=300)
```

Comment: Please click [edit] and format your code properly - indentation matters in Python. You also say you have saved your plots but don't show that code.

Comment: I have corrected the code and indentations

Answer (score 0):

I'm not near a machine to test, but you should be able to save the matplotlib figure into an `io.BytesIO`, i.e. a memory buffer, rewind it and open it as a `PIL Image`. You can then accumulate the `PIL Images` in a list and pass them to the `save()` function of PIL to write a GIF.

Untested, but something like:

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image

imlist = []
for ...
    ...
    ... your code
    ...
    # Make in memory buffer and save fig into it
    buf = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(buf) # you may need "PNG" as type here
    buf.seek(0)
    im = Image.open(buf)
    imlist.append(im)

# Save list of images as animated GIF
imlist[0].save('animated.gif', save_all=True, append_images=imlist[1:])
```

Comment: It worked wonderfully, now i just have to adjust the number of steps and wait for the gif. Thank you!